# Convert MongoDB Collection to Array of Nested Object

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My mongo data are in the following format:

```
{ country: "Bangladesh", city: "Dhaka", name: "Jobayer", email: "jobayer@gmail.com" }
{ country: "Bangladesh", city: "Dhaka", name: "Mehotaz", email: "mehotaz@gmail.com" }
{ country: "KSA", city: "Dammam", name: "Jabal", email: "jabal@gmail.com" }
```

I want to retrieve data like below:

```
[
    {
        country: 'Bangladesh',
        cities: [
            {
                city: 'Dhaka',
                contacts: [
                    {
                        name: 'Jobayer',
                        email: 'jobayer@gmail.com'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Mehotaz',
                        email: 'mehotaz@gmail.com'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        country: 'KSA',
        cities: [
            {
                city: 'Dammam',
                contacts: [
                    {
                        name: 'Jabal',
                        email: 'jabal@gmail.com'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I have tried some group operations but could not get the expected result. Please provide your valuable suggestion on how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is `$group` twice, once on `country x city` and then on just the country, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        country: "$country",
        city: "$city"
      },
      contacts: {
        $push: {
          name: "$name",
          email: "$email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.country",
      cities: {
        $push: {
          city: "$_id.city",
          contacts: "$contacts"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pW6rTShBZ4e)